# Storing data for desktop application

Tags: c#, mono

I mainly develop Java EE webapps so I don't have any experiences with desktop application at all. Now a friend of mine needed a little tool for daily business which I've build with Seam and a MySQL db in the background. In case of my experience this was done really fast.

Now I want to go further and produce a real small desktop app for him. I've looked at various options and developing a `gtk#` application with `Mono` seems my way to go for this little project. The application should be small and fast so I was thinking if a whole MySQL server is needed for my solution here.

What options I could evaluate instead of a database server which has to run as a service on the workingmachine? Storing data as `XML`?

To clarify the application has now 6 entites (Products, ProductTypes, Colors, Sizes, Orders, Production). On daily basis orders and production are added to a ProductType, very simple stuff.

Comment: Take a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML would work for small sets up data, but if you are going to have larger sets I would recommend something like sqlite.

http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: Ok, well I don't bother with XML then. I'll look if I need an ORM for this little project (NHibnerate or somethingelse) or if some basic sql statements would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at various options and I tend to like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

for client applications on .NET.  It is a file based solution that does not require a database server to be installed on the machine, much like using an Access database but better.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Can be other DB will interest, for example, [Db4o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db4o) or [SQL CE 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2).

Comment: I'll look into Db40 too. Thanks Dmitry